# Iphone responsive website issue

Tags: html, css, iphone, responsive-design, web

I am creating a new website, here is the [www.qldmetals.com](http://www.qldmetals.com/)

Everything seems to be fine on website except its responsiveness on iPhone. In iPhone the logo sits over the navigation menu. I tried the following media query, but it doesn't seems to be working for me i.e

`@media only screen 
      and (min-device-width : 320px) 
      and (max-device-width : 568px) { .logo a.brand { display: block !important; }}`

I'm confuse, Is this error because of display method or anything else (like I have to use media query for any other class)

I appreciate your help and your valuable time.

Thank you.

Comment: @MaryMelody I appreciate your help, but i found a solution. Thank you. cheers!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen your website and after that i have created some of my own style element which i am sharing it's only for media screen max width 480px 
Following Code

```
 @media (max-width:480px){
.logo a.brand {
    display: block !important;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    width: auto;
}

.logo a.brand img {
    float: none;
    height: auto;
    margin: 2px 8px 2px 0;
    width: 100%;
}

header .logo{
 float: none;
    max-height: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}


}
```

Comment: Amazing, that's work like a charm!! I changed this a bit to work in landscape mode as it was working on a portrait mode only <code> @media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 568px) { </code>, however thanks a lot for this help. Cheers!!